# How can I add `aarch64-none-elf` to my Rust toolchain?

Tags: rust, operating-system, arm64, toolchain

While beginning my work on CS140e today I've completed phase 3 of the project (writing C code to speak directly to GPIO pins on a Raspberry Pi 3 which would simply blink an LED) but on phase 4, once I attempt to compile my solution in Rust, `rustc` seems to not be able to find the `aarch64-none-elf` target:

```
➜  phase4 git:(master) ✗ make
+ Building target/aarch64-none-elf/release/libblinky.a [xargo --release]
WARNING: the sysroot can't be built for the Stable channel. Switch to nightly.
warning: `panic` setting is ignored for `test` profile
   Compiling rlibc v1.0.0
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`
  |
  = note: the `aarch64-none-elf` target may not be installed

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error: Could not compile `rlibc`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
Makefile:35: recipe for target 'target/aarch64-none-elf/release/libblinky.a' failed
make: *** [target/aarch64-none-elf/release/libblinky.a] Error 101
```

and, indeed, `rustc --print target-list` doesn't include `aarch64-none-elf`:

```
➜  phase4 git:(master) ✗ rustc --print target-list
aarch64-linux-android
aarch64-unknown-cloudabi
aarch64-unknown-freebsd
aarch64-unknown-fuchsia
aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
aarch64-unknown-linux-musl
aarch64-unknown-openbsd
        ...
```

Though I have installed the toolchain:

```
➜  phase4 git:(master) ✗ whereis aarch64-none-elf-gcc
aarch64-none-elf-gcc: /usr/local/bin/aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-gcc
```

Also, I have a custom target file named `aarch64-none-elf.json` with these contents (presumably passed to `xargo` when building):

```
{
  "abi-blacklist": [
    "stdcall",
    "fastcall",
    "vectorcall",
    "thiscall",
    "win64",
    "sysv64"
  ],
  "arch": "aarch64",
  "data-layout": "e-m:e-i8:8:32-i16:16:32-i64:64-i128:128-n32:64-S128",
  "executables": true,
  "linker": "aarch64-none-elf-ld",
  "linker-flavor": "ld",
  "linker-is-gnu": true,
  "llvm-target": "aarch64-unknown-none",
  "no-compiler-rt": true,
  "features": "+a53,+strict-align",
  "max-atomic-width": 128,
  "os": "none",
  "panic": "abort",
  "panic-strategy": "abort",
  "position-independent-executables": true,
  "target-c-int-width": "32",
  "target-endian": "little",
  "target-pointer-width": "64",
  "disable-redzone": true
}
```

Comment: The conclusion is use rustup ? ;)

Comment: @Stargateur But it looks like rustup doesn't have `aarch64-none-elf` toolchain too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do was run `rustup default nightly` and use the nightly version of `rustc`, as mentioned in the warning and I'm able to get past that error. If anyone want's to explain *why* this is, that'd be nice.

```
➜  phase4 git:(master) ✗ rustc --version
rustc 1.30.0-nightly (33b923fd4 2018-08-18)
```